# Javascript filter array empty objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

The 1st set of code works fine and assigns non-empty objects to the var, but the 2nd code with only log the right data but will not return the data. The var just remains undefined.

Any idea on where I am going wrong? Thanks!

```
var filteredEmpty1 = json_data.children.filter(function(value, index, arr) {
    if (value.children.length != 0) {
        return value//Returns what I need
    } else {
        console.log("EMPTY")
    };
});


json_data = filteredEmpty1;
json_data = {
    "name": "RVs",
    "children": json_data
};

var filteredEmpty2 = json_data.children.forEach(function(value) {
    value.children.filter(function(e) {
        if (e.children.length != 0) {
            console.log(e)//Logs what I need to return
            return(e)//Returns undefined
        } else {
            console.log("EMPTY")
        };
    });
})
```

Comment: The reason is because `forEach` doesn't return anything - it just iterates over the elements, but doesn't return a new array or anything.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In the latter, pay most attention to the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem". In this case we need to see an example of what is in `json_data` prior to the code shown. Also, it is likely that this code is run in the context of an asynchronous method. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2))` instead of console.log.

Comment: The callback you pass to `filter()` should always return a boolean value. `true` if it should be kept in the resulting array, false if it shouldn't. You are returning either `value` or (implicitly due to the absence of an explicit `return` in the else-branch) `undefined`. If you're unfamiliar with something, [check the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The forEach was my guess for why it was not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map instead of forEach because Map returns a value. and Filter function always returns boolean.

```
var filteredEmpty2 = json_data.children.map(function(value) {
    return value.children.filter(function(e) {
       return e.children.length != 0;
    });
})
```

Comment: This does work, but only returns the 3 child arrays into a new array. They are each under parents, where they need to stay.

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: 'THOR', free: true, description: '', url: '', 
children: Array(16)}
1: {name: 'FOREST RIVER', description: '', free: true, url: 'https://www.forestriverinc.com/', children: Array(7)}
2: {name: 'WINNEBAGO', description: '', free: true, url: 'https://www.winnebago.com/', children: Array(3)}

(3) [Array(11), Array(6), Array(2)]
0: (11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
2: (2) [{…}, {…}]

Each 1 of the arrays in the lower section need to be nested under its parent as shown above.

Comment: I am not understanding properly but may you want like this.

`var filteredEmpty2 = json_data.children.map(function(value) {
    let arr = value.children.filter(function(e) { return e.children.length != 0 });
    return { ...value, children : arr };
})`

Comment: that is exactly it. Thanks so much. I've been beating my head on filtering out the empty. Each child has a type and I got the filter by type working, but it left the arrays empty in some cases. This takes care of that.